# How to work with Flipkart Proteus Library in Java?

Tags: proteus

I am trying to work with Proteus library but i am not getting how to implement the functionalities of the library.
Can somebody please explain or share some java code to get me understand it better.

Answer (score 0):

The best way to play around with Proteus is to clone the open source repo and run the demo. You will find instructions in the readme.

If there is something else in particular you should ask it as a question on SO.